# How to add a fourth tab to this 3 tab example GUI?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, mfc, tabs

I have been working with [this demo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17439/CMyTabCtrl-Very-Simple-Dynamic-Tab-Control-for-MFC) (it has 3 tabs)

For the life of me, I can't seem to get a fourth tab to work.

Here is a portion of my sample code below.

```
CMyTabCtrl::CMyTabCtrl()
{
m_tabPages[0]=new CTabOne;
m_tabPages[1]=new CTabTwo;
m_tabPages[2]=new CTabThree;
m_tabPages[3]=new CTabFour;

m_nNumberOfPages=4;
}

CMyTabCtrl::~CMyTabCtrl()
{
for(int nCount=0; nCount < m_nNumberOfPages; nCount++){
delete m_tabPages[nCount];
}
}

void CMyTabCtrl::Init()
{
m_tabCurrent=0;

m_tabPages[0]->Create(IDD_TAB_ONE, this);
m_tabPages[1]->Create(IDD_TAB_TWO, this);
m_tabPages[2]->Create(IDD_TAB_THREE, this);
m_tabPages[3]->Create(IDD_TAB_FOUR, this);   /* Error occurs here */

m_tabPages[0]->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
m_tabPages[1]->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
m_tabPages[2]->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
m_tabPages[3]->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
```

This is the error that shows when I try running my program:

```
Error: m_tabPages[3]    0x00000000 {CDialog hWnd=???}   CDialog
```

The demo works great with 3 tabs, but I can't seem to add any more to it. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you created the IDD_TAB_FOUR in the resource?

Comment: @Jeeva Yes, the resource file has these settings: "#define IDD_TAB_ONE                     129
#define IDD_TAB_TWO                     130
#define IDD_TAB_THREE                   131
#define IDD_TAB_FOUR                    132"

Comment: What i am asking is have you created the dialog IDD_TAB_FOUR

Comment: @Jeeva, see my comment to satuon in the question section below. It relates to this comment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't have IDD_TAB_FOUR defined in your resource file (that is the .rc file, not resource.h). It is not enough just to define a resource ID in resource.h. For example,

```
#define IDD_TAB_FOUR 132
```

is just a define, it substitutes IDD_TAB_FOUR with the number 132.

You need to create a dialog from the resource editor.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned... the above code is only a sample. I am fairly well versed in C++. Yes, I have created a dialog from the resource editor. I was hoping that somebody had used the same tab demo and knew a few tricks for adding a fourth (and fifth) tab. Since I have duplicated everything I can think of and am unable to recreate another tab.

Answer (score 1):

m_tabPages[] was created with only 3 [3] elements so go ahead and change that to 4 or 5 or whatever in the header file it's in.